# The line $y=x$ is an invariant set ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, set-invariance

Let the system
\begin{align*}
    \dot{x} &= y^3 -4x\\
    \dot{y} &= y^3-y-3x
\end{align*}

(a) Prove that the line $y=x$ is an invariant set.

(b) Prove that $|x(t) - y(t)| \to 0$ when $t \to \infty$, for all other trajectories.

I have some questions of this exercise. For (a) I proposed the function $V(x,y)=x-y$, then I calculated $\dot{V}(x,y)$ and evaluate the function in the points $y=x$. The result I got was that $$\dot{V}(x,y)|_{x=y}=0$$
but then I do not know how to conclude. Is this right? For (b) I do not know well how to proceed.

Any hint?

Comment: If you are on $y=x$ then $\dot{y}=y^3-y-3x=y^3-x-3x=y^3-4x=\dot{x}$, i.e. $x$ and $y$ have the same rate of change and thus you remain on $y=x$ for all time. This is essentially what you have done but in more words. For the second part, do you know about critical point analysis of these types of ODE systems?

Comment: oooh now I get it. For the second part I have to calculate the Jacobian and evaluate in the critical points?

Comment: I think one critical point will be when $y=x$, right?

Comment: Critical points are when $\dot{x}=0=\dot{y}$

Comment: Ok, so in this case we have the critical points $(0,0),(2,2),(-2,-2)$ right?

Comment: The thing is I do not get the connection with the problem

Comment: The posted answer gives one method. Another option is to consider the critical points, classify them, and deduce the resulting phase plane, which would show all trajectories converge to $y=x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First question. We subtract the two equations and we get:

$ x'(t)-y'(t)=-(x(t)-y(t))$. We define $z(t)=x(t)-y(t)$ then we get :

$z'(t)=-z(t)$ which gives $z'(t)+z(t)=0$ multiply by $e^{t}$ and get:

$(e^{t}z(t))'=0$ which gives $e^{t}z(t)=c$. If for some $t_{0}$ we have $x(t_{0})=y(t_{0})$ then $z(t_{0})=0$ and

$c=0$ and hence $z(t)=0$ for all $t$, i.e.

$x(t)=y(t)$ for all $t$. So $x=y$ is invariant.

Second question. By the same equation for $c\neq\,0$ we obtain $z(t)=ce^{-t}$ and clearly

$|z(t)|=|x(t)-y(t)|\to 0$ when $t\to +\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! Such a wonderful answer.